# Abs of boolean expression

Tags: vb.net

In VB6 I have such code:

> IsLast = Abs(CursorPos = Len(numText.Text))

What evaluates false to 0 and true to 1.

This line of code produces error in VB.NET.

How to write this properly?

EDIT:
The error is:

```
Error   15  Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Abs' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
'Public Shared Function Abs(value As Decimal) As Decimal': Argument matching parameter 'value' narrows from 'Boolean' to 'Decimal'.
'Public Shared Function Abs(value As Double) As Double': Argument matching parameter 'value' narrows from 'Boolean' to 'Double'.
'Public Shared Function Abs(value As Single) As Single': Argument matching parameter 'value' narrows from 'Boolean' to 'Single'.
'Public Shared Function Abs(value As Long) As Long': Argument matching parameter 'value' narrows from 'Boolean' to 'Long'.
'Public Shared Function Abs(value As Integer) As Integer': Argument matching parameter 'value' narrows from 'Boolean' to 'Integer'.
'Public Shared Function Abs(value As Short) As Short': Argument matching parameter 'value' narrows from 'Boolean' to 'Short'.
'Public Shared Function Abs(value As SByte) As SByte': Argument matching parameter 'value' narrows from 'Boolean' to 'SByte'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IsLast = If( CursorPos = Len(numText.Text), 1, 0 )
```

Are you trying to migrate a larger chunk of VB6 to VB.Net?

Comment: Can you do an inline `If` like that or should it be `IIf`?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to migrate larger chunk of code. Shouldn't here be IIf instead of If?

Comment: Inline If  [has been legal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) for a while now. If you are using an older version of VB.Net, use IIf.

Comment: +1 for pointing out a short-circuit evaluator! Nice, and thanks, MarkJ!

Answer (score 1):

```
IsLast = CursorPos = Len(numText.Text)
```

Comment: Very interesting! I have to check this.

Comment: That will evaluate false to 0 and true to -1, but OP wants True to evaluate to 1. (BTW also requires Option Strict Off, which is bad.)

Comment: This will set `IsLast` to `True` or `False`. If `IsLast` is supposed to be an `Integer`, then I'd go with MarkJ's solution.

Comment: Yes, IsLast should be an integer and arguments should be of boolean type. That's why I uses Abs.